# Populating, Filling QTreeView tree on a separate thread

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to fill a QTreeView object on a separate thread. The information I want written to it is a folder+file list that is on a network drive. Iterating through the subdirectories takes a lot of time, so I don't want to block the Gui thread during this operation.

Here is my code :

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:

    void doWork(QString &parameter){

        QString data;

        QDirIterator it(parameter, QStringList() << "*.xml", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            QString currentFile = it.next();
            emit resultReady(currentFile);
        }
    }

    signals:
        void resultReady(QString &result);
    };

class iUSMDatabaseComposerWindow:public QMainWindow{
        Q_OBJECT
        ...

        QThread workerThread;
        QEventLoop loop;
    public:
        iUSMDatabaseComposerWindow(){
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

        bool success = connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater())); assert(success);
        success = connect(this, SIGNAL(getFilesInFolder(QString &)), worker, SLOT(doWork(QString &))); assert(success);
        success = connect(worker, SIGNAL(resultReady(QString &)), this, SLOT(appendToTree(QString &))); assert(success);

        //For Qt5 : connect( &workerThread, &QThread::started, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
        success = connect( &workerThread, SIGNAL( started() ), &loop, SLOT( quit() ), Qt::DirectConnection ); assert(success);
        workerThread.start();
        loop.exec(); // wait for thread initialization

        QString targetFolder (TARGETFOLDER);
        emit getFilesInFolder(targetFolder);
    }
    signals:
        void getFilesInFolder(QString &folderToProcess);
    private slots:
        void appendToTree(QString &file);
```

What I'm experiencing is that the connect() is successful but the Worker's slot (doWork) is never called by the emit getFilesInFolder(targetFolder). I noticed that if I add the Qt::DirectConnection when connecting to the doWork() slot, it does call it.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Remove `QThread workerThread;` from `Worker` class. It this a typo?

Comment: ok, removed. Code updated as suggested, now using the eventLoop as well. P.S. I used the Qt::DirectConnection to block in the loop.exec().

Comment: .. I don't think a simple delay would do it. I tried long long i = 650000000;
while (i-->0); which on my machine requires about a second with /Os. Seems that the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to emit a signal after thread initialization is done:

```
QThread t;
// connect here
QEventLoop loop;
connect( &t, &QThread::started, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
// for Qt4: connect( &t, SIGNAL( started() ), &loop, SLOT( quit() ) );
t.start();
loop.exec(); // wait for thread initialization

emit YourSignal();
```

Your problem: you are emitting signal before thread initialization is done. `QThread` starts an event loop after thread is created. But in your case, event loop can't get in time with initialization, so your emit does nothing.

Comment: would be helpful!
I cannot compile the example : 

 error C2248: 'QThread::started' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'QThread'.

I tried: 

 Worker *worker = new Worker;
 worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

 QEventLoop loop;
 connect( &workerThread, &QThread::started, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
 workerThread.start();

Comment: What version of Qt do you use?

Comment: version 4.7.1, 64-bit. It's a constraint of the project, cannot change. :(

Comment: I updated my answer. I used a Qt5 syntax to connect slot

Comment: Ok, compiles for Qt4 as well now. However, not working yet. I declared the loop object as a member. The slot still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to call the workers's doWork() slot by directly connecting to the worker's started() signal :

```
success = connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(doWork())); assert(success);
```

This works, however does not answer the question to the original problem..